# Detect a “Error: Object doesn't support this property or method”

Tags: vbscript, error-handling

The object I’m working on is instantiated in JavaScript, but used in VBScript. In one code path, the variable `M.DOM.IPt` is defined and has a value, in the other however it is not. I need to detect if it has been defined or not. I checked that `M.DOM` is defined and accessable in both code paths. Every test I have tried simply results in this error:

> Error: Object doesn't support this property or method

I have tried:

- `IsEmpty(M.DOM.IPt)`
- `M.DOM.IPt is Nothing`
- `isNull(M.DOM.IPt)`

Is there any way to detect the variable isn’t defined and avoid the error?

Note: I can put `On Error Resume Next` in and it will simply ignore the error, but I actually need to detect it and conditionally do something about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Function SupportsMember(object, memberName)
      On Error Resume Next

      Dim x
      Eval("x = object."+memberName)

      If Err = 438 Then 
        SupportsMember = False
      Else 
        SupportsMember = True
      End If

      On Error Goto 0 'clears error
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

```
On Error Resume Next
Err.Clear
MyVariable=M.DOM.Ipt
If Err.Number<> 0 Then
    'error occured - Ipt not defined
    'do your processing here
Else
    'no error - Ipt is defined
    'do your processing here
End If
```

Comment: This seems to the best and only solution. Seems like a bad hack, but I'll have to use it.

Comment: Actually marxidad offered more elegant solution, based  on same approach - but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried On Error Goto label?

Comment: That's not supported in VBScript--only On Error Resume Next

Comment: Well, that and On Error Goto 0.